# Evaluating the integral of brownian motion with respect to time with defined limits of integration

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

I am trying to evaluate the integral
$$\int_0^1 W_t dt.$$


Using Ito's Lemma, I have got to the point where I can say

$$W_1 = \int_0^1 t dW_t + \int_0^1 W_t dt,$$
but this has not helped me evaluate the integral. Are there any methods for evaluating this limit or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: there is no "closed form" for this integral. However it can be shown that it is a Gaussian random variable, and its mean and variance are not hard to compute.